# Linear affine random dynamical systems - positive Lyapunov index proof check?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, random-matrices

Consider the affine random dynamical system
$$
X_n = \mathbf A_n X_{n-1} + R_n, 
$$
starting from an initial non-zero position $X_0$, where $\mathbf A_n\in\mathbb C^{d\times d}$ and $R_n\in\mathbb C^{d}$ are both constructed from i.i.d. zero mean circularly symmetric complex Gaussian variables whose mean and variance do not depend on $n$. Is it possible to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n|| \geq 0?$$

**Here's what I have.**

Firstly, we   see that for $\alpha_n,\beta_n\in\mathbb C^d$,
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\alpha_n+\beta_n|| \leq \max\left\{ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\alpha_n || \;, \;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\beta_n|| \right\}\;(1)\end{equation}
since $||\alpha_n +\beta_n||\leq 2\max\{  ||\alpha_n||, ||\beta_n ||\}   $. Furthermore, $(1)$ holds with equality when
\begin{equation}
\min\left\{ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\alpha_n || \;, \;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\beta_n|| \right\} < \max\left\{ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\alpha_n || \;, \;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\beta_n|| \right\}. \;(2)\end{equation}

Considering the system under question, we have
\begin{eqnarray}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n|| &= &\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\mathbf A_n X_{n-1} + R_n|| \\&\leq& \max \left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||\mathbf A_n X_{n-1} + 0.5R_n||  ,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||0.5R_n||     \right\} \;(3) \\&=&\max \left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n||  , 0  \right\} . \end{eqnarray}

If  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n|| \geq 0,$$  our result is reached trivially; if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n||  = \lambda< 0,$$ we reach a contradiction because (from $(2)$) $(3)$  holds with equality, which gives $\lambda=0$.